# Functions running when not being called

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using Python and TkInter to build a GUI where a certain command is called when a button is pressed. The relevant code looks like this:

```
class Main(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
    self.generate_noise_button = Button(root, text="Add noise and save", command=self.generate_noise())

 ...


def generate_noise(self):
    header.generate_noise()
```

If I place a breakpoint in the `generate_noise()` method and run the program, the breakpoint is instantly hit despite never being called or the button being pressed. Furthermore whenever I actually do press the button the method is never called making the button completely useless. Why?

Answer (score 1):

```
self.generate_noise_button = Button(root, text="Add noise and save", command=self.generate_noise())
```

When you provide a `command` argument, you're not supposed to add parentheses to the end.

```
self.generate_noise_button = Button(root, text="Add noise and save", command=self.generate_noise)
```

You want the `command` to refer to the method object, not the value that the method returns after it is called.